# Django Model - how do I tell Django to look for a customized ID instead of the default

Tags: python, django

I have two tables, Team and Voting. For my Team table, I'm using a customized ID called "id". In my Voting table, I have a foreign key named "team" to refer to the Team table. I'm also making that "team" attribute a primary key.

The problem is that when I go to the registered route for the Voting table, it gives me an attribute error **"Team' object has no attribute 'team_id"**

I assume it's because by default Django is looking for an ID called "team_id" in my Team table instead of my customized ID called "id".

How do I solve this?

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Team(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="", primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Voting(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    thumbUp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    thumbDown = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from teams.models import (
    Team,
    Voting
)


class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = "__all__"


class VotingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # team = TeamSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Voting
        fields = "__all__"
```

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import (
    TeamViewSet,
    VotingViewSet
)

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("api/teams", TeamViewSet, "teams")
router.register("api/voting", VotingViewSet, "voting")
```

**api.py**

```
from teams.models import Team
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .serializers import (
    TeamSerializer,
    VotingSerializer
)

# Team ViewSet
class TeamViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Team.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = TeamSerializer


# VotingSerializer ViewSet
class VotingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Team.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = VotingSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class VotingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Team.objects.all() <-- here is the problem, it should be Voting.objects.all()
```

btw: if `Voting.team` is primary key it looks you are implementing OneToOne relationship.